# Symfony 5.4 routes by annotations not working

Tags: linux, apache, symfony

I know this question has been discussed million times here, but it is the third day I keep on struggling on this issue.

I've got symfony application been developed on my local PC (Windows). Now I'm trying to deploy it on my linux web-hosting (Linux).

My routes are initted in controllers' classes via annotations.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Category;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app_index")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('index/index.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'IndexController'
        ]);
    }
}
```

The issue is these routes are not included by some reason, which leads to 404 error

**/config/services.yaml**

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

  App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
      - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
      - '../src/Entity/'
      - '../src/Kernel.php'
...
```

**/config/routes/annotations.yaml**

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:
      ru: '' # don't prefix URLs, the default locale
      en: '/en'

kernel:
    resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
    type: annotation
```

**/config/routes.yaml** is empty

`symfony console debug:router` shows only **admin** and **profiler** routes but not mine initted in controllers

I would be very grateful if you could help me solving this issue.

If I describe the index route in **routes.yaml** (which I don't like.. What are the annotations then for?)

```
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\IndexController::index
```

symfony goes wild
`"App\Controller\IndexController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?`

All I've done during deployment was:

1. clone git repo with my application on the production server
2. installed composer dependencies
3. migrated database structure
4. updated env with new db connection

Comment: Verify the file `config/routes/annotations.yaml` exists.  That is what tells Symfony to scan your controller directory for annotated routes.  If one does not exist then create a new 5.4 project and copy the file out of it.

Comment: And the `no container set` is a completely different issue.  It just means you don't have your controller services autowired properly.  Once again looking at what a new 5.4 project has should help.  Even once you get your routes defined via annotations, the service error will continue.  Starting to suspect that  you are trying to update your app as well as moving it to linux.

Comment: Hey, Cerad! The annotations.yaml exists, I've just added it's contents in the question.
p.s. I've added symfony/apache-pack - without it even profiler routes couldn't be resolved
p.p.s. I've updated both projects during this struggle, they seem to be all the same

Comment: Okay so I did not realize that this was a deployment issue even though you said it in your question.  You need to follow the docs for your particular deployment.  All kind of things can go wrong.  Make sure you built the cache for production.  And there won't be any profilier stuff in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with PHP 8 attributes

```
#[Route('/', name: 'app_index')]
```

function:

```
#[Route('/', name: 'app_index')] 
public function index(): Response {
    return $this->render('index/index.twig');
}
```

Documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.attributes.overview.php

Comment: Thank you very much. It did help.

I've had PHP 7.4 on my prod server. Updated it to PHP8 and rewrote routes to attribute style. Finally it works.

Comment: it's a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Symfony 5.4 project with:

```
symfony new --webapp --version=lts foo
```

And PHP 8.2 was installed.

But annotations (in PHP attribute format) would not work. That is, my new routes would not appear when issuing `php bin/console debug:route`.

But the following command fixed it:

```
composer require annotations
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope auto wire is enabled in service.yaml

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
```

And please comment code in **routes.yaml**
And try with `php bin/console cache:clear` command.

Comment: hey, thank you for your feedback! Yes, it is enabled (updated the post).
cache:clear doesn't help :(

Comment: @Bhavin Glad I am not the only one that misunderstood the question.  It would appear that this an application that works fine on a development machine but not so much when deployed.  The symptoms are very strange.  And the OP seems oddly reluctant to reveal any details about how they are deploying except for the operating system being used.

Comment: Well, I don't realize what is really important here because I'm new to symfony. Added depoyment steps.
The reason I've told about dev and prod systems only, because these steps I've taken were enough to make a working copy of the web application on the same dev machine

Answer (score 0):

You must require:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

After that just change FollowSymLinks to SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ... and "vu à la" ... This package reconfigure Your code for Apache web-server ...